# $_FILES[$file][type] php variable value

Tags: php, mime-types

Some years ago there was an opinion, that $_FILES[$file]['type'] contains mimetype sent from a browser, but not real mimetype, for example here:

http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.files.php#109902

Is it still so and do i still need to use fileinfo extension to detect mimetype?
(i am using php5.4)

Comment: Depending on the file types you expect, it might not be necessary to install an extension. What would you like to be able to detect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `type` is populated with data provided by the browser.

From the manual page about [POST method uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php):

> $_FILES['userfile']['type']
>
> The mime type of the file, if the browser provided this information. An example would be **"image/gif"**. This mime type is however not checked on the PHP side and therefore don't take its value for granted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's still the case. The `type` is the client-provided MIME information.

Answer (score 1):

I always use fileinfo for this, but if you use a flash uploader maybe you will find that almost every file uploaded with the flash uploader is detected as `application/octet-stream`.

Because this... I also have a "mimetype detection from extension" method that, in case the file is detected as `application/octet-stream` by fileinfo, it will check it's extension and try to determine the real file type.

Comment: But if you already use fileinfo, why do you care about the extension?

Comment: Because the flash player usually changes the file headers... and there's no way to detect the mime type. It always return `application/octet-stream`. So I need to get the content type from the extension (I repeat... only when it's detected as `application/octet-stream`).

Comment: Unless Flash modifies the file itself, fileinfo should be able to detect it. The idea is to detect the *contents* of the file, not what the browser *says* it is.

Comment: Well, if you don't have the headers issue with file info should be enough.

Comment: You shouldn't even *look* at the headers. If you look at the headers, you might as well just use the `type` data you get in `$_FILES`.

Comment: Hhhmm.. thanks for the appointment. Now you said it I'm not sure if I have ever checked the type data on the $_FILES var. Maybe it preserves the original filetype..